# How to create HTTP GET request to google calendar API with c#?

Tags: c#, web-services, google-api, calendar, http-get

Hello guys I am newbie and I am creating http get request to google calendar api, I just want to get event data with eventid and calendarid

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/get
this is link of google api, where you can also test API

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
        private static JavaScriptSerializer _Serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string CalendarID = "somecalendar@group.calendar.google.com";
            string EventID = "someid";
            {
                string URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+ CalendarID + "/events/"+ EventID;
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                var cust = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"somecalendar@group.calendar.google.com", "someid" }

        };
                var json = _Serializer.Serialize(cust);
                string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cust);
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
                requestWriter.Write(data);
                requestWriter.Close();
                WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                responseReader.Close();

                Console.WriteLine(response);
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

in the end console writes this exception:

> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with
>   this verb-type.

can someone help?

Comment: Well per their doc, "Do not supply a request body with this method." You should not send data when using the verb "GET". The part where you write your data shouldn't be there